# Javascript counter works only once

Tags: javascript, timer

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/5z2vu47a/

It's a simple timer that should change text that taken from and array

The timer only works once.

Why does the timer not continue to work.

```
var name_arr = ['learn', 'product', 'buying', 'selling', 'marketing', 'managing', ];
var counter = 0;

function names(){
    alert(counter);
    $('.text p').text(name_arr[counter]);
    counter++;
    alert(counter);
}

setTimeout(names, 1000);
```

Comment: Use `setInterval` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: use setInterval instead of setTimeout

Comment: _"Why does the timer not contiue to work."_ Why should it?

Comment: Just repeat the `setTimeout` call within the `function names().` http://jsfiddle.net/5z2vu47a/2/

Comment: Can't understand the downvotes... =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

```
setInterval(names, 1000);
```

In the `names` function, also check that the counter value should not exceed the `name_arr.length`.

```
function names(){
    alert(counter);
    $('.text p').text(name_arr[counter]);
    if(counter<(name_arr.length-1))
     counter++;
    else
     counter=0;
    alert(counter);
}
```

Comment: "... should not exceed the name_arr.length" - Nice catch

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` runs only once, after a specified delay.
As stated in MDN [WindowTimers.setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

> Calls a function or executes a code snippet after a specified delay.

`setInterval` runs in intervals, spaced by a specified delay. 
As stated in MDN [WindowTimers.setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

> Calls a function or executes a code snippet repeatedly, with a fixed time delay between each call to that function. Returns an intervalID.

So, `setInterval` will run forever, unless you break it with a `clearInterval`.

```
function doStuff() {
    // Doing ome nice and fancy stuff here...
}

var interval = setInterval(doStuff, 1000);

// this will stop the interval loop
clearInterval(interval);
```

Answer (score 0):

You used `setTimeout`, which waits 1 second and then does your function.

You want `setInterval`